# Solving complex ODE in python with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve a system of complex ODE with scipy running the code below, but I get the error:

```
  line 9, in f
  f0 = -1j*g/2*np.conj(y[1])*y[2]

  TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import complex_ode

def f(y, t):
    g=1.+0j,
    f0 = -1j*g/2*np.conj(y[1])*y[2]
    f1 = np.conj(+1j*g/2*np.conj(y[2])*y[0])
    f2 = -1j*g/2*y[0]*y[1]
    return [f0, f1, f2]


t0=0;
y0=np.array([100,1,1], dtype=np.complex128)

r = complex_ode(f)
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)

t1 = 10
dt = 1

sol = np.array([], dtype = np.complex256)
t   = np.array([], dtype = np.complex256)

while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    t=np.append(t,r.t+dt)
    sol=np.append(sol, r.integrate(r.t+dt))

A1 = sol[:, 0]
A2 = sol[:, 1]
A3 = sol[:, 2]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, abs(A1), label='A1')
plt.plot(t, abs(A2), label='A2')
plt.plot(t, abs(A3), label='A3')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('A')
plt.title('A-t')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

How can I fix this? It seems that the function `f` alone is working, but when it's called by the integrator it results in an error.

Comment: When you use `ode`, the signature of `f` must be `f(t, y)`; see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you I fixed this, however this not solve the problem

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the line `g=1.+0j,`, which makes `g` into a tuple with length 1 that contains the value `1+0j`.  Remove that comma.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem, thank you
There were other simple problems also, but I've managed to correct these